# How to capture from CMakeLists.txt file what was passed as generator name?

Tags: cmake

I want to be able to forward the generator value (for example via `execute_process`). Is there any CMake define or function to get `-G` value or autodetected one?

Comment: https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables

Comment: In general you cannot execute the generator name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CMAKE_GENERATOR`, cf. the documentation https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/variable/CMAKE_GENERATOR.html